# python 3 sql into with pandas and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, insert-into

I have a pandas DataFrame,df, that I want to append to a remote table TabB on a postgres db. Both tables shares the same columns. How can I perform this using pandas and sql alchemy?

My sqlalchemy engine is defined as this:

```
myengine=create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:5433/mydb')
```

I would like to know if I can apply a method like `df.read_sql()` to pass a proper `INSERT TO`. Any example would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In `pandas=0.20.3` I generally use something like that:

```
db_engine=create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:5433/mydb')
df_to_save.to_sql(con=db_engine, name='yourTable', if_exists='append', index=False)
```

`df_to_save` and `yourTable` needs to have the same columns